# Insert element to binary tree at specific position

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

It might be an newbie question but I am struggling to get an answer to this question. Consider an binary tree(not binary search tree) like this:

```
              root
      child1        child2

  child3 child4
```

I need to add "child5" at the left child of "child2". How an I do that? I know the way to add nodes for binary search tree. Snapshot of the same is something like this:

```
if (newNode->val < root->data) {
  -> pick left node
} else {
  -> pick right node
}
```

Since tree is not an BST, this solution would not be correct.

An pictorial representation of what I am trying to say:

```
               1
      2                3

  4      5
```

In above tree, '6' should be added as left of '3'.

Comment: But the tree *is* a binary tree? Is there any order to the nodes and leaves? The it is the same as a BST.

Comment: *Why* should the node be added there? Is this a special case or does it follow from any rules? Do you perhaps want to add a node in the next "free" position in a balanced tree?

Comment: @molbdnilo, No, it is not from any rule. Thought of this while solving some other problem. And yes, that is true, want to add a node in the next "free" position in a balanced tree?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, In that case, '6' would go to the right of '3'. Correct?

Comment: So the *ordering* is not important, but the *balancing* is? Then you should edit your question to state that requirement. Maybe update the example tree to not be (somewhat) ordered.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, But the tree is not ordered right now also. By looking at the number, it looks ordered.

Comment: @HemantBhargava "add a node in the next 'free' position" is a rule. That kind of tree is usually called "complete". You should be able to find suitable algorithms both online and onpaper.

Comment: @molbdnilo Would the answer make sense to you?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Would the answer make sense to you?

Comment: @HemantBhargava I think so. You could trade time for space if you store in each subtree whether it is full or not.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I think answer to this would be something like this:

Little tweak in BFS would be required. When you pop up the items from the queue, check if any of the children is empty. The first empty child slot is the place you want to add to.